# How can I extract the tables, text and the pictures in ODT(OpenDocumentText) format using Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, odt

How can I extract the tables, text and the pictures in an ODT(OpenDocumentText) file to output them to another ODT file using Python on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

[OOoPy](http://ooopy.sourceforge.net/) seems to be a good fit. I've never used it, but it comes with documentation and code examples, and it can read and write ODT files.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to just rename the `foo.odt` to `foo.zip` and then extract it. the extracted directory contains many files including Pictures.

However I think it's better to change it's type to `docx` and then do the process on `docx` (extract it). Because it extract images with better name (image1, image2, ...).